# Time Complexity evaluation

Tags: time-complexity

Write the recurrence equation T(n) for time complexity of following algorithm. Then, solve the recurrence equation and evaluate the time complexity.

```
Algorithm (n, k)
{ 
   If(n < 1)
   {
       Print("Error");
    }
    Else
    {
       For ( i = 1 ;i<=k,i++)
       {
          A[n] = i
          Algorithm (n - 1, k)
       }
   }
}
```

I was expecting the answer would be O(k^n).So what can be the answer please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `k` never changes in the function so can be regarded as a constant and the function can thus be treated as taking a single parameter `n`.

Each call to `Algorithm` on `n`, results in `k` calls to `Algorithm` being made on `n-1`. So the recurrence relation modeling the function is `T(n) := k * T(n-1)` which, indeed, yields `O(k^n)` time complexity.